# Is it possible to use nodejs dependencies on an Electron App?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, electron

I am working on a serverless app with its administration built on Electron/Angularjs, all de database is being administered from there, and works perfect.
Now I need to add some Admin functionality provided by the [Firebase Admin API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) now, I understand that there is a way to load Node Modules on Electron.

Can please anyone point me on the right direction, documentation, ideas, etc.

Or you think its a better idea to build Amazon AWS Lambdas to work this requirements?

If I find a solution I will be posting it here.

Comment: Electron is  a disguised node server so basically speaking you can install and run almost any module written for node in electron with  npm install & require

Comment: am I missing something that makes angularjs relevant to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require node modules using `require` in `electron` because it is a combination of Chromium, Node.js, and other libraries.

```
const myPackage = require('some-node-package')
```

So, if you do `process.versions` in electron interactive mode or in a script, you will get this;

```
> process.versions
{ http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '6.5.0',
  v8: '5.3.332.47',
  uv: '1.9.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  modules: '50',
  openssl: '1.0.2h',
  electron: '1.4.12',
  chrome: '53.0.2785.143',
  'atom-shell': '1.4.12' }
```

Which means, Electron has `Node v6.5.0`.

> However, for native modules, you may require rebuilding your application. See this for more details: https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild